# Is it possible to suppress single-click events during a double-click?

Tags: macos, qt, winapi

Our application supports single click and double-click events on a window which do different things. However we always get a single-click event during the double-click which causes undesired effects.

Our application is in Qt but really this is a question about underlying Windows/Mac APIs - is this a fundamental detail that the OS detects a single click as soon as you lift your finger since it can't possibly know you are going to click a second time, or can it be prevented?

If it can't be prevented, is their an accepted best practice how to handle it?

Comment: The behavior cannot be changed. The common approach to deal with this is a user interface design, where the single-click operation doesn't interfere with the double-click operation. E.g. in Explorer, a single-click selects an item, whereas a double-click invokes the default operation on the selected item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start a timer when you get `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` (or Qt equivalent).  If you get `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` (or Qt equivalent) before the timer expires, cancel the timer and execute your double-click action. Otherwise, when the timer expires, execute your single-click event.

On Windows, you can get the double-click time using `GetDoubleClickTime()`.

That's about the best you can do - you can't prevent the single click message being generated in the first place on either platform.

Comment: `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`? I would prefer [`Qt::MouseButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MouseButton-enum) constants for this. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Sure, if that is easier, I don't know Qt

Comment: Can you clarify explicitly that single-click up/down events _cannot_ be suppressed in your answer, as you imply and the comment on my question states? Just to make it more complete so I can accept it?